# Current Date to UILabel using NSDate

Tags: ios, date, uilabel, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm simply trying to take the current year, and display as text. I want to do this for copyright reasons, ex: `©2012` would automatically become `©2013` on January 1st.

```
-(void)getYear {

    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY"];
    copyrightDate.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
}
```

This however is not working when "copyrightDate" is set as a `IBOutlet` and connected to a `UILabel` in Interface Builder. Does my code check out, or is it something new in iOS 6.0 about labels and such?

Comment: Use lower case. "YYYY" is used for "Week of Year" based calendars: [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];

Answer (score 0):

If `copyrightDate` is an IBOutlet pointing to a `UILabel` your code look ok.
Possible source of error
1. when you are doing `copyrightDate.text` ->  `copyrightDate == nil` That would be the case if you are trying to set the date before `viewDidLoad` is called on your view controller.
2. `copyrightDate` is not currently hookup with your IBOutlet
3. your iVar name is `_copyrightDate` instead of `copyrightDate`, but at this point I would suggest doing `self.copyrightDate.text = @"some text";`